# How to extract first few lines from a csv file inside a tar file without extracting it in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, csv, tar

I have a tar file which has lot of csv files in it. 
How to get the first few lines of each csv file without extracting it?

I tried:

```
$(tar -Oxf $tarfile $file | head -n "$NL") >> cdn.log
```

But got error saying:

```
time(http:index: command not found
```

This is some line in one of the csv files. Similar errors are reported for all csv files...
Any idea??

Comment: That's correct, you're trying to evaluate several first lines of file. Remove $().

Comment: To elaborate what @keltar said, say `tar -Oxf $tarfile $file | head -n "$NL" >> cdn.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `-O` you can tell tar to extract a file to standard output instead of to file. So you should be able to first use `tar tf <YOUR_FILE>` to list the files from archive and filter it using `grep` to find the CSV files, and then for each file use `tar xf <YOUR_FILE> <NAME_OF_CSV> -O | head` to get the file's beginning to stdout. This may be a bit ineffective since you unpack the archive as many tiems as there are CSV files, but should work.

Comment: I tried this.
for file  in $(tar -tf "$tarfile")
        do
 cdn.log=$(tar -Oxf $tarfile $file | head -n "$NL")
        done

where NL is the number of lines... But didnt work

Comment: I tried
    $(tar -Oxf $tarfile $file | head -n "$NL") >> cdn.log
But got error saying...
    time(http:index: command not found
"time(http:index:" This is some line in the csv file....
Any idea??

Comment: It just can't be as you say it. Please post your complete script. Looking to another your question that differs only slightly - i have a feeling you doing something completely wrong.

Comment: My full script:

    #!/bin/bash
cd /root/Chithra/ProbeLogs/CDN


PER=10

for tarfile in `ls *.tar`
do
        for file  in $(tar -tf "$tarfile")
        do
                #file=`echo ${file##*/}`
                echo CSV File: $file
                NL=$(tar -Oxf $tarfile $file | wc -l)
                echo $NL
                mul=`expr $NL \* $PER`
                NL=`expr $mul / 100`
                echo $NL
               `$(tar -Oxf $tarfile $file | head -n "$NL")`>>cdn.log
        done
done

Comment: @user1407668 why you're reading only NL lines, if NL is line count of entire file? It doesn't making sense. Use `cat` without parameters (not related to your problem - just less cryptic). As for your latest problem - you have answer in comment for question. $() notation (and grave-accent, not sure how to type this symbol on stackoverflow..) means 'take output of command' - in `for` list you need this, but in last command you just trying to execute actions stored in file and redirect resulting output to file - but it's clearly not shell commands (and not what you wanted to do, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and its `Archive::Tar` module. Here a one-liner that extract the first two lines of each one:

```
perl -MArchive::Tar -E '
    for (Archive::Tar->new(shift)->get_files) { 
        say (join qq|\n|, (split /\n/, $_->get_content, 3)[0..1]) 
    }
' file.tar
```

It assumes that the `tar` file only has text files and they are `csv`. Otherwise you will have to `grep` the list to filter those you want.